# Unable to host angular 7 application on gcp cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, angular7, google-cloud-run

I have built an Angular 7 application that works correctly when I run `ng serve` command from my local machine using docker.
This is a simple hello world angular application(without database).

When I am trying to host my application on GCP Cloud Run. It is giving me port error.

Error in cloud run :

**Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
Deployment failed
Creating Revision......failed
Setting IAM Policy...............done
Deploying...
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [test-case-builder] in project [test-case-builder] region [us-central1]
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
```

Here is my docker file

```
    FROM node:latest as node
    # set working directory
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    RUN npm install
    RUN npm run build --prod
    FROM nginx:alpine
    COPY --from=node /app/dist/test-case-builder usr/share/nginx/html
    CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to listen on the port defined in the `PORT` env var.  So in your `Dockerfile` do:

```
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

Comment: I just published Host Angular8 application on Google Cloud Run https://link.medium.com/m5nLWGdNW2